# Can a Silverlight MediaElement open a video from the client?

Tags: silverlight

Can a Silverlight MediaElement open and play a video from the client, after it is selected from an open file dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. You can only source a Uri, but not a file:// one because you cannot read local folder information.

Answer (score 1):

Else, you can upload the client file to the server, then use it as video source thru its url.